# The CKEditor not function when I've clicked the modal box in second times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem adding the CKEditor function in the popup modal box. When I've clicked the button to open the popup modal for the first time, the CKEditor function can work. If I've clicked the button to open the popup modal for the second time, the CKEditor function cannot work and show the textarea HTML. Modal box id `mesyuarat_modal` cannot use the same id because will affect my coding in the next function.

Below is my sample coding, just show two rows of data in the table:

```js
let theEditor;

    ClassicEditor
      .create(document.querySelector('#agenda_mesyuarat_edit'))
      .then(editor => {
        theEditor = editor;

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });


    function getDataFromTheEditor() {
      return theEditor.getData();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/10.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Button</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#mesyuarat_modal" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="Help" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-color-format="hex">Open Modal</a></td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#mesyuarat_modal_2" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="Help" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-color-format="hex">Open Modal</a></td>
    <td>AGH</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
<div id="mesyuarat_modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Draft</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="mesyuarat_content">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="agenda_mesyuarat_edit" id="agenda_mesyuarat_edit" value="" title="Agenda Mesyuarat">
                                            </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div id="mesyuarat_modal_2" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Draft</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="mesyuarat_content">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="agenda_mesyuarat_edit" id="agenda_mesyuarat_edit" value="" title="Agenda Mesyuarat">
                                            </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have to console of the browser。 No error message

Comment: What I can see, for the first row the **CKEditor** is attached but for the second, it isn't. Is that your issue?

Comment: Yes. Just can show 1 time only for CKEditor

Comment: @AT-2017 You can copy my code to test

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example how you can append **CKEditor** to number of rows in a table or div. You require to create dynamic instances of **CKEditor** in order to append them to table rows or dynamic data.

```js
//Index starts from 1, so you'll get CKEditor with unique ids
var index = 1;

//Click event, so you have any number of CKEditor created
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
     var newEditor = 'editor' + index; //Unique id for CKEditor
 
     $("#details").append('<textarea id="' + newEditor + '"></textarea>'); //Append it to a div for demonstration purpose

     CKEDITOR.replace(newEditor); //CKEditor unique instance attached
     index++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<div>
    <button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add CKEditor</button>
</div>

<div id="details">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your code is not working in the popup modal right? Because I tried it cannot work

Comment: It will not work in your code directly, you have to refactor it to make it work in yours. I just provided a sample how you can do it.